# Why and when dummy variable creation is important in python project?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

```py
Categorical_Vars = (FullRaw.dtypes == 'object') & (FullRaw.columns != 'Source')
dummyDf = pd.get_dummies(FullRaw.loc[:,Categorical_Vars], drop_first = True)
```

Comment: It depends on the project, could you be more specific on the project you're working on and what's your concern in this context about dummy variables?

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz Skibinski ! In my project, its mainly used to convert categorical variable to Numerical (Say Gender_Male to 1 or 0)

Comment: I guess then it makes sense - why - cause it reduces repetitions to minimum. It would be called passive data dictionary then - and regardless whether you have normalised, or denormalised data eco-system - it would be useful. Now I would recommend you to read something about data warehousing in general - and get some basic concepts